# How to embed an iframe in Confluence page?

Tags: iframe, confluence

I want to embed an iframe in a Confluence page, e.g. Google Calendar.

I insert the iframe code in Confluence page, it should show the calendar as follows:
[image]

But it just display the text of code as follows:

```
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=3g3ie767f4ji0e72icgtfjg%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;c" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

How to embed an iframe in Confluence page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Log in as your Confluence Admin, go to manage add-ons
2. Enable all the modules of the Confluence HTML Macros
3. Insert the Include HTML Macro when you are creating/editing a page.

   a) Go To Insert More Content > Other macros

   b) Search for HTML macro

   c) Paste the following code inside the macro
4. Save the page

```html
     <iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=3g3ie767f4ji0e72icgtfjg%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;c" noborder="0" width="830" 
     height="800" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
```

```
 <iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=3g3ie767f4ji0e72icgtfjg%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;c" noborder="0" width="830" 
 height="800" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
```

Comment: Hi @Ashiqur Rahman, thanks for your reply. However, I cannot find the HTML macro, my Confluence is v5.9.11. Which version do you use?

Comment: then u need to install it first ... and don't forget to accept my answer

Comment: Hi @Ashiqur Rahman, do you know where the HTML macro is? There seems no the macro in the Atlassian marketplace. How did you have the HTML macro? Is it installed by default?

Comment: Couldn't find “Manage add-ons” on the current Conflunece Cloud (version 1000.0.0-2de308a3ab52).
The other answer worked (search for "iframe macro")

Comment: @llias Bartolini ... It's for older version... Can't help you with the new version sorry

Answer (score 3):

When adding a macro I did the following:

1. "Other Macros"
2. Search for "iframe"
3. Select "Iframe" macro
4. Enter only the iframe url, and any other required settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Confluence Cloud**, the other answers won't work. That is because HTML macro is not included in Confluence cloud version by default.

There are addons in Atlassian Marketplace that enable this feature.
You can check out:

**[HTML Macro for Confluence](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221472/html-macro-for-confluence?hosting=cloud&tab=overview)**

This addon allows embedding any external web contents as iframe.